# Remove all duplicates of movie clip (snow effect)

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, duplicates

Hello I'm making Christmas card on flash and I put some snowflakes from [this tutorial](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/mx/snow.htm)
The problem is that every snowflake is created over everything else on the stage and I need to hide all snowflakes for some frames to make transmission between two scenes.
Transmission is transparent black rectangle over the scene and alpha is slowly going to 100%... but the snowflakes are visible over the black rectangle - how to remove them all ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a specific MovieClip for the snow effect, this MovieClip would act as a container for your effect. Instead of adding the snow mcs directly to the stage, you would add them to the MovieClip that's added to the stage.

Whenever you need to hide the snow, simply hide the MovieClip.